# Swift Alamofire discover in LAN

Tags: request, timeout, alamofire, app-transport-security, swift4.2

In my LAN, I run the following Terminal command on 6 MAC computers to host a folder in which is `discover.xml`:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 17171
```

On my app having `Alamofire` installed, I run this code in order to get `discover.xml` content:

```
extension String {
    func url(file: String) -> URL {
        return URL(string: "http://\(self)/\(file)?rand=\(arc4random())")! // `rand` to make sure no cached content
    }
}

func discover(from ip: String, completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
     let url = ip.url(file: "discover.xml") // ip passed in: "192.168.1.15:17171" for ex

    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    request.timeoutInterval = 6.0 // !

    let manager = Alamofire.SessionManager.default
    manager.session.configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 6.0
    manager.session.configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 6.0

    manager.request(request).responseData { (response) in
        switch response.result {
        case .success(let d):
            // do my stuff on `multiX`

        case .failure(let error):
            print("failed with IP: \(ip) => \(error)")
        }
    }        
}
```

Below is how I discover:

```
private func discover(on subnet: String) { // subnet: 192.168.1
    let group = DispatchGroup()

    for i in 1..<256 {
        let ip = subnet + ".\(i):17171"

        group.enter()
        discover(from: ip) {
            group.leave()
        }
    }

    group.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) { [weak self] in
        guard let strongSelf = self else { return }

        print("all done: \(strongSelf.multiX.count)") // just can discover 2, or 3, or 4 !!
        strongSelf.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Why most of the time, I cannot get 6 `discover.xml` from the 6 MAC computers? (I can only get 2 or 3, or 4).
The result that I get is not persistent. Say I have 6 MAC computers running `python -m ...` named: A, B, C, D, E, F. Sometimes I can only get: A, B, D, sometimes C, F, ...

Requesting the remaining computers which host `discover.xml` always have error `failed with IP: x.x.x.x:17171 => Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out."` (I'm sure those missing computers have acquired the IP successfully)

Is it ok to discover the whole subnet using my method above? (i.e. using for loop to iterate each ip). Is 6 seconds a reasonable timeout?

EDIT:

I have tried to allow all in ATS, but things are not better

[image: ATS]

What actually blocks me from requesting `discover.xml` on the MAC computers?

Thanks,